# react:Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react project, I now open through webstorm no problem, but directly open the folder inside the `index.html`, the main page can be out, but a click will be being given, click on the link I used reactor。
Trouble who can help me solve, thank you！

Error message：

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A
>   history state object with URL
>   'file:///Users/qinchen/Desktop/change/dist/integralpage' cannot be
>   created in a document with origin 'null' and URL
>   'file:///Users/qinchen/Desktop/change/dist/index.html'.
>       at finishTransition (file:///Users/qinchen/Desktop/change/dist/bundle.js:25897:24)
>       at file:///Users/qinchen/Desktop/change/dist/bundle.js:13142:13
>       at file:///Users/qinchen/Desktop/change/dist/bundle.js:13118:9
>       at next (file:///Users/qinchen/Desktop/change/dist/bundle.js:25765:7)
>       at Object.loopAsync (file:///Users/qinchen/Desktop/change/dist/bundle.js:25769:3)
>       at confirmTransitionTo (file:///Users/qinchen/Desktop/change/dist/bundle.js:13104:17)
>       at transitionTo (file:///Users/qinchen/Desktop/change/dist/bundle.js:13130:5)
>       at Object.push (file:///Users/qinchen/Desktop/change/dist/bundle.js:13153:5)
>       at Object.push (file:///Users/qinchen/Desktop/change/dist/bundle.js:13395:15)
>       at Object.push (file:///Users/qinchen/Desktop/change/dist/bundle.js:6535:15)

Comment: Can you be a bit more explanatory on where you are getting this exception etc, guess it is in webstorm

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use pushState when loading up a local file (a file:/// URL in your browser), which is for security reasons. Instead, you have two options:

1. Use a Hash history instead. This will work fine on a local file.
2. Start up a simple web server to serve up your file instead. If you don't want to build a small server application, [here is a list of simple ones](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255). You can take your pick and they will all give you a http:// URL in your browser that supports the Browser history.

Comment: I am now the project must be directly open index.html use，
That means my only solution is to use a Hash history instead？

Comment: Quote reactor index.html is written like this：                                       
render(
    <RouterIndex history={hashHistory} />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);

Answer (score 0):

install/Use Web Serve and serve the build folder. it will work.

The easiest way to handle this would be to install serve and let it handle the rest:

```
npm install -g serve
serve -s build
```

The last command shown above will serve your static site on the port 3000. Like many of serve’s internal settings, the port can be adjusted using the -l or --listen flags:

```
serve -s build -l 4000
```

Refer - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/