# react-router-dom project breaks because of publicPath when bundling with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router-dom

Im working on a project with React-router-dom.

in my webpack I set:

```
output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/'
},
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
}...
```

I need `publicPath` to be `"/"` in order for the routes to work (*unless im wrong*)

When I run the project with `webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --process`,
everything works fine.

But when I try to build and bundle it, I get this error:

> index.html:11 GET file:///C:/app.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Do you know what would be the right way to configure it so the build would work fine as the project runs fine with webpack-dev-server?

Comment: How are you serving your app after you have built it? The server that's going to serve the app needs to know about client routing. Can you try [local web server](https://github.com/lwsjs/local-web-server) and serve your app from the build folder with `ws --spa index.html`?

Comment: @margaretkru I was trying to run it with no server at all, just by opening my index.html,

why do I need a server ? cant I just run in staticly ?

Comment: it would actually work, but I am guessing you need to change paths in the html from `/app.js` to `./app.js` to load the file in the same directory as the html and not at the root of the current web, then enable "Allow access to file URLs" in Chrome Extensions, described [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools#faq). But the react routes will no longer work if your serve the app from `file:///`.

Comment: btw, are you using `HashRouter` or `BrowserRouter`? according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44403064/6053299) your routes will work if serving from file system and using `HashRouter`, otherwise you have to set up a web server.

Comment: @margaretkru  true, true :) i am using HashRouter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here we go, how to run react app from `file:///`.

1. Change `webpack` configuration of the `output` section making `publicPath: './'`, for example if `index.html` and bundled files are located in the same directory:

   ```
   entry: ...
   output: {
       path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
       filename: '[name].js',
       publicPath: './'
   }
   ```

This will allow to load bundled files in the same directory as the html and not at the root of the current web (as it would be in case `publicPath: '/'`).

2. If testing in chrome, enable "Allow access to file URLs" in Chrome Extensions, described [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools#faq).
3. If using routing, use `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter` (concerns `react-router` v4). See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44403064/6053299) for more information on this.